# automatic email via Outlook from vba

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have been working and did some Google searches to create code that sends an automatic email with information from my active Excel sheet. The code prepares the email properly, but I still need to press "Send" on the email. I would like to send it automatically, so I tried to add `.Send` on the code, but it didn't work.

At the moment my code looks like that:

```
Sub CreateMail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngCc As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = .Range("t2")
    Set rngSubject = .Range("t3")
    Set rngBody = .Range("a1:r35")
End With
rngBody.Copy

With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .Display
End With
SendKeys "^({v})", True
.Send
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngCc = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: try replacing `.Display` with `.Send` ( and removing the .Send+.SendKeys outside the with block )

Comment: i tried, now the email is sent but blank.. it does not copy the information

Answer (score 1):

```
With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .body = rngBody.Value
    .Send
End With
```

Should do the trick. (Note: I set the body of the message, since you seemed to have missed that.)

remove these lines:

```
SendKeys "^({v})", True
.Send
```

Comment: I just pasted the code into an Excel workbook and was able to send a message (thanks for the code, BTW, I've been meaning to head this direction, but haven't yet.) I hard coded the `To`, `Subject` and `Body` values, and had no issue. I don't see any reason why pulling them from a spreadsheet cell would be any different. Give it a try with hard coded values, just for a test.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three different ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a plain text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word Editor. Outlook uses Word as an email editor, so you can use it to format the email message. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.

The simplest way to get the job done is to use the Word object model for modifying the message body. For example:

```
mail.GetInspector().WordEditor
```

Then you can use the Word object model for working with message body.

Finally, you need to call the Send method to submit the message for processing by the transport provider.

Answer (score 0):

here is complete <kbd>**code**</kbd> that is working for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateMail()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngCc As Range
Dim rngBCC As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = .Range("T2")
    Set rngCc = .Range("T2")
    Set rngBCC = .Range("T2")
    Set rngSubject = .Range("T3")
    Set rngBody = .Range("A1:R35")
End With
rngBody.Copy

With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .CC = rngCc.Value
    .BCC = rngBCC.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rngBody)
     ActiveWorkbook.Save
    .Send
End With
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngCc = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
         Cells(1).Select
         Cells(1).Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
         Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Publish the sheet to an .htm file.
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    ' Read all data from the .htm file into the RangetoHTML subroutine.
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    ' Close TempWB.
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Delete the htm file.
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```