# Excel: Send outlook email based on cell content

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to learn:

When it is 16 days past the date in a certain column(column D), how do we send an outlook email to the email address (format: name@abc.com) which is listed in another column C. eg. An email should be sent to the email address in C1 if the date is 16 days past the date in cell D1 and the cell E1 is blank(has no text).

Also, how can I set up the body of the email in a way such that I can insert a string into the body by taking the text in another column B. eg. the body of the email sent to the email address in cell C1 should contain the string of text in cell B1.

[image: Image eg.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a `Worksheet_Change` event on the code page of your worksheet where you are having data as shown in your snapshot.Open VB Editor by pressing `F11` key. Then you click on sheet, it will open up code page of the sheet. From the drop down select change and a routine will be added to the code page. Insert code in that routine.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 7 Then   'e.g. for column G
          Sendmail   'name of your sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Set up of our sheet is like the snap shot shown below.

[image: email_on_due_date]
I have considered following points.

- There should be an alert only and system should not automatically send mails without review.  Many times worksheet events give unexpected results as such caution is required here.
- To provide latest status I have entered following formula in `F2` cell which will be `"YES"` or `"NO"` depending upon date in `D2` cell and `E2` status.
- For worksheet event to work properly a Cell in `Column G` has to be clicked. I have added a form control button in cell `G2`. When status is yes click the button in `G2` to send the mail.
- Now Insert a module in the workbook in VBE and put the code of `Sendmail` in that module.
- Subject is in cell `F1`, body of message apart from general salutations is in cell `B1`, Name of the recipient is in cell `C2`

  ```
  Sub Sendmail()
          ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
          ' changed.
          ' Place your code here.
  Dim answer As String
  Dim SubmitLink As String
  Dim KeyCells As Range

   Set KeyCells = Range("F2:F100")
  SubmitLink = Range("B1").Value

  answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to save this change. An Email will be sent to the User", vbYesNo, "Save the change")

  If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
  If answer = vbYes Then

   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'open outlook type stuff
  Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  On Error Resume Next

  'add recipients
  'newmsg.Recipients.Add ("Name Here")
  newmsg.Recipients.Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
  'add subject
  newmsg.Subject = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value
  'add body
  newmsg.Body = "Dear Customer, " & SubmitLink & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & " Look Forward to your confirmation" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & "Sincerely," & vbLf & "Customer Care department"

  newmsg.Display 'display
  newmsg.Send 'send message

  'give conformation of sent message


   MsgBox "Modification confirmed", , "Confirmation"



  End If
     '     MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
   On Error GoTo 0
   Set newmsg = Nothing 
   Set OutlookApp =Nothing

  End Sub
  ```

EDIT : OP comments location of codes shown in snap shots

[image: worksheet-change]
[image: module location]

Comment: Is it possible to send the email without clicking the button?Or even without opening the excel file? Would it be possible to just automatically send the email on the date 16 days past the checkout date?

Comment: Also, could you kindly guide as to where exactly the 2 pieces of code need to go. I do not see the 'change' drop-down for the routine to be added to the code page. Also, how do I add a module in the workbook? I am relatively new to using this functionality in excel.

Comment: @coderrr I have edited my post to show locations . You can go to VBA Editor after pressing F11. I have uploaded sample file HERE<https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7vqsc0xr9p5qku/54814335-send_email.xlsm?dl=0> which shall provide you further help. Please note that I have mentioned that we have used worksheet_change event. Target Column is `G` . You have to click anywhere in column `G` to send email.

Comment: @coderrr Error handling is possible to incorporate. I deliberately avoided because I felt you are at basic level like me and code lines like `On Error Resume Next` suppress the error and makes debugging for error difficult. I shall incorporate code of error handling a little later. During testing it was revealed that worksheet_change does not fire the sending of email automatically unless we click in the target range. There are programs on SO which send email depending upon cell value in Excel Sheet but I have not tested these programs yet and would not suggest without testing at my end.

Comment: @coderrr you may like to refer this SO link which is a different approach and may e more suitable for you.  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927151/automatically-send-an-email-if-a-specific-cell-value-exists-include-adjacent-va>

Comment: I was assuming that the 2nd chunk of code would go in a macro for the button but I will try using the code in a module.

Comment: @coderrr what you desire is covered in referred post but I have not yet tested this approach. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124859/automatic-email-via-outlook-from-vba> If you are satisfied with the help provided by me in your proceeding further in the matter then please accept my answer by clicking a tickmark below down pointing arrow beside question.

Comment: @coderrr This SO Post is more closer to your requirement <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316409/excel-vba-to-send-email-reminder-every-28-days-from-a-date>

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just have a few questions:

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just have a few questions:1. What is the use of 'KeyCells' in the code. I ask because, I need to be able to use the Yes/No to determine whether an email needs to be sent for that row. There may need to be multiple emails sent per row if value in column F is 'Yes' for that row. Therefore, I think there needs to be a loop integrated somewhere which I am not sure how to do as the email Id to which the email is sent and the email body would be different according to data in that specific row.

Comment: @coderrr `KeyCells` is just a variable name where I have set a formula to determine whether condition regarding age of email `=IF(AND(TODAY()>(D2+16),E2=""),"YES","NO")`. This can be copied down to other rows also. It determines `Yes` and `No` condition. I think it will be better that you post a new question after referring to references provided me and finalizing your requirement. Looping in general is possible but it would depend what approach you take and prefer,whether worksheet_change event or only cell based value without event firing.